# Create XLS File with Multiple Sheets

Tags: csv, reports, varien

I found this class in Varien `Varien_Convert_Parser_Xml_Excel` however, I couldn't find any source on how to create an XLS file with multiple sheets in it.

Note that it needs to be XLS not CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported at the moment so I just used the `PHPExcel` library.